# Moment Js produce invalid date in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, momentjs

Hello any one having idea why i am getting "invalid date" in Safari, in other browsers works as expected.

```
moment('01/01/2023 11:44:00.000 AM').tz(time_zone, true).format('hh:mm:ss:SS A z')
```

chrome

[image: chrome]

safari

[image: safari]

I have tried something like

```
.replace(/ /g,"T")
```

but no luck any idea what to try?

Answer (score 0):

Look like this will work, provide date format as second param.

```
moment('01/01/2023 11:44:00.000 AM', 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS`').tz(time_zone, true).format('hh:mm:ss:SS A z')
```